# Python Logging Formatter: print the logger name

Tags: python, logging

How can I change the logger format in order to print the logger name?

Desired output:

```py
>>> import logging
>>> logger = logging.getLogger('AI Service')
>>> logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
>>> logging.basicConfig(format='[%(levelname)s] %(???)s - %(message)s')
>>> logger.info("Starting service")
[INFO] AI Service - Starting service
```

Is this possible? I can't find a 'formatter' option to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide logging format to support it. In your case, you can define something like below

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s:\t%(name)s:\t%(levelname)s:\t%(message)s')
```

This will show the time, module name, log level and message.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is just a google away: `%(name)s`.

Comment: The documentation also has a list of all the attributes the LogRecord has by default: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes